# Multiple pages view of the same PDF

Tags: swift, pdf, macos-sierra

I am using PDFView from PDFKit (swift programming language, macOS) in order to display some PDF documents.
I would like to display multiple pages of the same PDF. 
A solution would be to create multiple PDFView from the same PDF but in this way I have to allocate multiple time the same memory and this can be a problem for PDF rich in images.
Is there any fast way to display different pages of the same PDF in, say, 4/8 different views?

EDIT: 
The precious suggestions of @danielv brought to this code

```
import Cocoa
import Quartz

class PDFPageView: NSView {

    var pdfPage: PDFPage?

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
        if(pdfPage != nil) {
            let context = NSGraphicsContext.current()
            let pdfBox = PDFDisplayBox.mediaBox        
            let pdfBounds = pdfPage?.bounds(for: pdfBox)
            let scaleX = visibleRect.width/(pdfBounds?.width)!
            let scaleY = visibleRect.height/(pdfBounds?.height)!
            let scale = min(scaleX,scaleY)
            context?.cgContext.scaleBy(x: scale, y: scale)
            pdfPage?.draw(with: pdfBox, to: (context?.cgContext)!)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple pages of same pdf"? PDFView already displays multiple pages with a scrolling view, do you want do display them in a different way?

Comment: @danielv ultimately what I would like to do is to have a "triple single page", so having three PDFView about the same PDF but I don't want to triplicate the used memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PDFView`most likely won't serve well for the purpose of displaying multiple pages of the same PDF document.

But you can to do it yourself. `PDFPage` can draw itself to any given graphics context. You can create a subclass of `NSView` to draw a page or use other more fancy views like `NSCollectionView` and draw pages to its rows/columns/grid.

Here is roughly how you'd do it with NSView:

Create a subclass of NSView

```
class PDFPageView: NSView {

    var pdfPage: PDFPage?

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)

        let context = NSGraphicsContext.current()!

        pdfPage?.draw(with: .mediaBox, to: context.cgContext)
    }
}
```

**Important:** you will need to transform your view's context before drawing to fit the page and make up for any page rotations. `PDFPage` has some helper functions for this.

Also note that `draw(with box: PDFDisplayBox, to context: CGContext)` is since MacOS 10.12, to support previous versions use `draw(with box: PDFDisplayBox)`

In your controller, load the PDF document and assign each page to the view that needs to display it.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var pdfPageView: PDFPageView?

    var pdfDocumenet: PDFDocument?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "... pdf filename ...")
        pdfDocumenet = PDFDocument(url: url)

        pdfPageView?.pdfPage = pdfDocumenet?.page(at: 0)

    }
}
```

Edit (to include author's comments):

When you try draw the PDF page on the NSView's context, the page drawing doesn't respect the view's bounds. Try it yourself, you will see what I mean. You need to do the scaling of the context yourself, usually by transforming the current graphics context to the desired coordinates. Search for Cocoa Drawing Guide for detailed information about contexts and transformations. PDFPage provides some helper methods to let you get the original page bounds and the transformation that the page may have used to rotate the page, if it was needed.

To get the page's rect you use bounds(for box: PDFDisplayBox), not the context size. You need to transform the context before you draw on it. But it's all in the docs, you really need to read the Cocoa/Quartz Drawing Guides and the docs for PDF page. So be sure to take a look there.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please explain me better the sentence "Important: you will ... function for this". I have not understood what the problem is.

Comment: When you try draw the PDF page on the NSView's context, the page drawing doesn't respect the view's bounds. Try it yourself, you will see what I mean. You need to do the scaling of the context yourself, usually by transforming the current graphics context to the desired coordinates. Search for _Cocoa Drawing Guide_ for detailed information about contexts and transformations. `PDFPage` provides some helper methods to let you get the original page bounds and the transformation that the page may have used to rotate the page, if it was needed.

Comment: I have tried with this but it does not work (sorry for the bad formatting)

        `let context = NSGraphicsContext.current()

        pdfPage?.draw(with: .mediaBox, to: context!.cgContext)
        var pdfWidth = (context?.cgContext.width)!
        var pdfHeight = (context?.cgContext.height)!
        var scaleX = visibleRect.width/CGFloat(pdfWidth)
        var scaleY = visibleRect.height/CGFloat(pdfHeight)
        context?.cgContext.scaleBy(x: scaleX, y: scaleY)`

I think a better option (if the code worked) would be to draw in a "invisible drawing context" and the to the real one.

Comment: What doesn't work? The drawing? The scaling? To get the page's rect you use `bounds(for box: PDFDisplayBox)`, not the context size. You need to transform the context **before** you draw on it. But it's all in the docs, you really need to read the Cocoa/Quartz Drawing Guides and the docs for PDF page...

Comment: I think I have found how to doing it. I will post my (hopefully) working code.

Comment: I got the code working but I have performance issues when changing page. Please see the linked question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40382516/load-multiple-pdf-pages-in-background-to-improve-performance?noredirect=1&lq=1